# How to parse a dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

i try to learn better dict in python. I am using an api "chess.com"

```
 data = get_player_game_archives(username).json


    url = data['archives'][-1]
    games = requests.get(url).json()

    game = games['games'][-1]
    print(games)
```

That's my code and they are no problem and the result is

```
{'games': [{'url': 'https://www.chess.com/live/game/8358870805', 'pgn': '[Event "Live Chess"]\n[Site "Chess.com"]\n
```

But i dont know how to get the "url",
i tried

```
    game = games['games']['url'] or
       game = games['games'][{url}]
```

obviously i misunderstood something, but i dont know what.

Thanks for your reading

Comment: `games['games']` is a list so you need an index to access its element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dictionary you have a key called `games`. The value associated to this key is a list of dictionaries (it starts with `[{`)
You need to loop on all the games as follows, assuming your dictionary is stored in the variable `games` :

```py
for game in games['games']:
  game_url = game['url']
  # your process on game_url
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! is there a diff between your code and "print(games['games'][-1]['url'])" ?

Comment: `games['games'][-1]['url']` will only get you the url of the last game. This is an important subtlety, if you receive multiple games you need to use a for loop.

Comment: Ok thanks! i understand quite better dictionnaries :)

Answer (score 1):

Is that the entire output? I don't see the closing curly brackets (`}`).
Either way, it seems like you can get the url like:

```
url = games['games'][0]['url']
```